# Create variables with for loop

Tags: javascript, variables, closures

I'm trying to create 20 functions stored in variables. Each one adds a specific amount of numbers to another quantity. Here's an example:

```
function creaSuma(x){
    return function(y){
        return x + y;
    }
}

for(let i=1; i<21; i++){
    add+1=creaSuma(i); //this doesn't work. How would you change it?
}
```

In this case:

```
console.log(add15(10));
```

the output should be 25

So, how would I create those 20 variables without creating an array? (I tried it and it works)
Thank you, it is just out of curiosity.

Comment: Use an object and let these be dynamic properties/fields of the object.

Comment: Oh, nice solution. Thank you

Comment: Why do you need these functions at all? There is usually no sense in keeping a few closures around. Why not `add(15, 10)` ?

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
function creaSuma(x){
    return function(y){
        return x + y;
    }
}

for(let i=1; i<21; i++){
    window['add' + i] = creaSuma(i); //this doesn't work. How would you change it?
}
```

```
console.log(add15(10));
```

will output 25

I'm using **window** for dynamic variable namings, as it has a reference to all global variables and global functions you are using.

You can alternatively use the same approach but with a custom object.

Comment: this looks exactly like the solution I have already mentioned in the comment :)

Comment: Not for the first part where I'm using the global **window** object so it would be stored as normal variables. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment to the original post, use an object and let these be dynamic properties/fields of the object.

Here is your modified code:

```js
function creaSuma(x) {
    return function (y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
var x = function () {

}
for (let i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    x['add' + i] = creaSuma(i); //this doesn't work. How would you change it?
}

console.log(x.add15(10));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!!